# Designing a class implementing a method which signature types depends on the instance contained

Tags: design, inheritance, class-design, abstraction, class-diagram

My goal is to define a `Service` class which `process` method accepts a `RequestType` argument that is defined by the contained `ServiceType` and returns an object of a type defined by `ServiceType`. By doing this I'm able to derive `Service`s that can process a given `Request` that is compatible with the type of the `Service` , same for the `Response`.

I really don't know if it is possible and the following diagram is obviously wrong but depicts the result I'm struggling to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many programming languages support generic types (C#), generics (Java) or class templates (C++). All three terms mean the same thing, but I honestly like the C++ terminology best. The term "class template" is good, because it implies that the class is not the actual class, but a *template* used by the compiler to create real classes. The intention is to solve the exact problem you are running into. I'll use C#, since that is the language I am most fluent with, but many OOP languages support this:

```csharp
public abstract class Service<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    public virtual TResponse process(TRequest)
    {
        // common logic goes here
    }
}
```

The identifiers inside the angle brackets `TRequest` and `TResponse` are just placeholders for real classes that will be specified when initializing a new service object:

```csharp
Service<GetBlogRequest, GetBlogReponse> service = new Service<GetBlogRequest, GetBlogReponse>();
GetBlogRequestrequest request = new GetBlogRequest(1200);
GetBlogReponseresponse response = service.process(request);
```

UML diagrams usually depict class templates or generics using the angle bracket notation as well:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|               <<abstract>>               |
| Service<TRequest, TResponse>             |
+------------------------------------------+
| +process(request : TRequest) : TResponse |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, the problem here is that `Service` accepts any derived type of `TRequest` and `TResponse`, I need to tied them under a common type so that `Service` can only accept a `TRequest` correlated with the specific `TResponse`

Comment: TRequest is not a class. It is a placeholder for a real class that is specified later when other code creates a new instance of the service. Some languages allow you to restrict which types can be specified in generics. For instance in C# you would do `class Service<TRequest, ...> where TRequest : RequestType`.

Comment: I wrongly expressed myself. My goal design is not to define a template because each different `Service` that accepts a different correlated couple of `<TRequest, TResponse>` must define a different `process` logic in advance

Comment: Ok. So override `process` in the child class, or make `process` an abstract method.

Comment: The language you're using feels like the Mediator pattern. @GregBurghardt is using a c# example - here is a good github repo that implements a more detailed version of what Greg was doing: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki